# PHP/Mysqli - GROUP BY get latest records but only for some records

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by

I run this query to GROUP BY session_id and get the latest (time) records:

```
$query = "SELECT type, session_id, session_name, session_email, time
FROM chat
WHERE time IN (
    SELECT MAX(time)
    FROM chat
    GROUP BY session_id
)
ORDER BY time DESC";
```

Yet, I only want the latest records for type and time. How can I still get the first records for session_id, session_name, session_email?

Comment: Define a second query and use UNION

Comment: Can you show me how you would do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = "
    SELECT type, session_id, session_name, session_email, time
    FROM chat
    WHERE time IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(time)
        FROM chat
        GROUP BY session_id
    )
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 5 /* gives you the first 5 records

    UNION

    SELECT type, session_id, session_name, session_email, time
    FROM chat
    WHERE time IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(time)
        FROM chat
        GROUP BY session_id
    )
    ORDER BY time ASC
    LIMIT 5 /* gives you the first 5 records in other sequence
    ";
```